# onenote todo tags (checkbox) aren't automatically continuing on the next line

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2010

I'm using OneNote 2010.

I haven't got much experience with this software, but everything I read tells me that if I create a todo tag (i.e. a checkbox at the beginning of the line) then when I hit enter, the next line should have one too; essentially the same as the behaviour for bullets in MS Word

if I press ctrl & 1 and then type something, when I hit enter, the cursor moves to the next line but there is no checkbox.

[image]

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Something else that I've noticed is that no matter what the paragraph spacing is on the paragraph where I'm typing, when pressing enter to start a new line the paragraph spacing is set to 0 again when I start a new line with enter.  That is to say, if I'm in a list with spaced out checkboxes, the cursor goes to the next line with no space between it, and no checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

### Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

What you expect works, if you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then the checkbox is created also on the new line. Tags other than checkbox are not duplicated this way.

Tested in OneNote 2016. The funny thing is I cannot find it documented in the [list of official shortcuts](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Keyboard-shortcuts-in-OneNote-2016-for-Windows-44b8b3f4-c274-4bcc-a089-e80fdcc87950). (Nor for OneNote 2010.)

Comment: this doesn't work for me in 2010.  Thanks though